# UBUNTU 22.04 LTS wifi Speed

Tags: networking

I changed from ubuntu 20.04 lts to 22.04 lts. All is ok but the wifi speed.
When changing the power setting to off with the iwconfig command it is ok.
How can I set the power off setting permanently?
Thanks in advance
Horst

iwconfig:
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"A1-Werdenich"
Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: D4:3D:F3:A5:9E:52
Bit Rate=117 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm
Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Power Management:off
Link Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:288   Missed beacon:0

inxi -N
Network:
Device-1: Intel 82577LM Gigabit Network driver: e1000e
Device-2: Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6200 driver: iwlwifi

Comment: Thanks for joining the Ask Ubuntu community. Can you please help by adding some additional information, as the current question is unclear. What is it that you're trying to do (what is your overall goal: it doesn't need to be a technical answer). For my own sake, I'm unclear as to how or why you associate WIFI speed with enabling/disabling the service (via the `iwconfig` command as you note). Thanks

Comment: To answer your question, we would need to know more about your hardware. `inxi -N`  and `iwconfig` should give us a clue. Paste the output and add it to your [question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1454251/edit), **not** into the comments

Answer (score 0):

Please try this terminal command:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Reboot.

Comment: There is no conf.d file

Comment: May we see: `ls /etc/NetworkManager` Thanks.

Comment: ls /etc/NetworkManager
conf.d        dnsmasq.d         NetworkManager.conf  VPN
dispatcher.d  dnsmasq-shared.d  system-connections
by typing ls I can see config.d but the file manager doesn't list it. Why?

Comment: Let's dig a bit deeper: `ls -al /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d`

Comment: I just changed the parameter wifi.powersave from 3 to 2 at:  /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d  file default-wifi-powersave-on.conf. This works very well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the parameter wifi.powersave from 3 to 2 at: /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d file default-wifi-powersave-on.conf. This works very well. Thanks –
Horst